# How to contain bounding box when element wraps on white-space?

Tags: html, css

Given the following example...

```css
/* Custom reset */

html {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0 50px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Problem code */

h1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  background-color: purple;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 3px;
}

h1::before {
  margin-left: -50px;
}

h1::after {
  margin-right: -50px;
}

h1>span {
  background-color: lightpink;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Fooooooooooo & Baaaaaaaaaar</span>
</h1>
```

When you run the snippet you'll notice a pink box with wrapped text (because it doesn't fit all in one line) and purple lines on the sides, like this:

[image]

And this is how it looks when the text doesn't wrap (which is OK and it's what I want):

[image]

In the first image there's too much space between the text and the purple lines and I need it to be only 20px, like the second image.

In other "words", I'm looking to achieve this:

[image]

(simulated image)

It goes without saying that I need this to work with dynamic content (the text could be anything, have any number of words, short or long). I also need the text to be in a single line if it fits, otherwise multiline and always with `20px` max between the purple lines and the text.

Comment: Can't you just set a fixed `width`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge How can I do that if the content is dynamic?

Comment: Well the content will span a varying amount of lines, sure, but you'll still have the same space between the pink box and the line :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm not sure I understand what you're saying so if you could put that into working code, that would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your end goal correctly, you could simply set a fixed `width` on the `<span>`. This will ensure that there's the desired amount of 'margin' around the pink box, and it will also work with variable content; if there's too much content to display on the one line, it will simply create more lines. Because the new lines are also constrained by the fixed `width`, the pink box will still retain the same amount of 'margin':

```css
/* Custom reset */

html {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0 50px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

div+div {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Problem code */

h1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  background-color: purple;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 3px;
}

h1::before {
  margin-left: -50px;
}

h1::after {
  margin-right: -50px;
}

h1>span {
  background-color: lightpink;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Fooooooooooo & Baaaaaaaaaar</span>
</h1>
```

Obviously the **value** you would need for the fixed `width` would depend on the context, but `350px` works pretty well for your example.

Comment: I see what you meant now but unfortunately it doesn't work as I expect it. My real examples won't work with a fixed width like that because they vary too much. I also want the text to be displayed in one line if the parent container allows it, multi-line if it doesn't. Sorry for not making that clearer.

Comment: And if you wanted to get fancy you could use a fixed percentage or `vw` so the span would change based on browser width. Getting **really** fancy you could probably also use `calc()`

Comment: No worries! You could always make use of media queries for something like that. Like only setting a fixed `width` at a certain breakpoint. I don't think a variable width would work in this case, as it would 'offset' the constraining `width`, sadly.

Comment: Also if you change `width` to `max-width` you might be able to get closer to the end goal.

Comment: I want to have just `20px` between the lines and the text, no matter if the text is single line or multi line and a fixed width just won't work.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral is this not what you are after: https://jsfiddle.net/egwwp3hx/ ? The only difference is `max-width` instead of `width`.

Comment: @JonP Almost... If you drag the preview container to make it wide, at least the second example text should fit in a single line but it remains in two lines. The text wrapping should be responsive too.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral How about: https://jsfiddle.net/egwwp3hx/1/ ? If that's what you need hopefully Obisian will edit them into their answer and you can accept it/

Comment: @JonP It's better but it still doesn't maintain a max of `20px` between the lines and the text. This question has been marked as duplicate and the answers on those questions resort mostly to JS to fix this issue, which I didn't want to :(